# Microsoft Word->Field Code->{TC}

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

[image: How it looks]

So I am having a problem.  This is what I can create on one of my laptop:

On another, when I created something that has {TC} in it, the whole field code disappeared.

For the example above, if on the other computer, both are running Office 2010,

I can input the code to create the table of content from:

> {TOC \f \h \z \f 1\t "Heading 1,1,Heading 2,2,Heading 3,3,Title,1}

to

> {TC}

The moment I type in TC, the whole {} disappears.

Other field codes work just fine, except for {TC}.  So my question is how do I get {TC} to show on my other laptop?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, I found my answer.

When I searched google for my answer, most sites give this as a solution:

[image]

For Word 2010, go to File->Options->Advanced

Under Show document contents:  Select "Show field code instead of their values"

This is the equivalent of pressing Alt+F9, which DID NOT solve my problem.

Apparently, the solution to get {TC} to show in your document is in:[image]

go to File->Options->Display

and check to always show HIDDEN TEXT.

I hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the disappearing TC code is annoying at first -- seems like it's broken. Other codes work, but why does that disappear, even if entering manually? Word instantly sets TC code to Hidden, even the field code itself.

To temporarily toggle this visible without permanently changing your display to show Hidden Text, you can use the normal Ctrl-Shift-8, which toggles display of spaces, paragraph marks, tabs, and Hidden Text, on and off. This is a good keyboard shortcut to have in your standard back of tricks anyway. It is frequent in Word that you need to toggle paragraph marks on and off, because paragraph formatting is attached to the Paragraph mark, and when they're hidden, it can be tricky to fix various formatting issues.

Answer (score 0):

The original post was a few years ago, but I fear things have gotten worse since then, not better. I am using Word 365 v2201, which should be up to date. The other day, I wasted hours on trying to resolve this issue with TC field codes.

First I tried entering them using Insert > Quick Parts > Field. Word creates what looks like a field code, but it behaves as normal text. Messing around with the various controls to toggle field display and hidden text etc etc, has absolutely no effect. It is basically a faux field. And of course, it is completely ignored when compiling the TOC.

Next, I tried entering it manually, by using Ctrl + F9 to either create a blank field or convert some existing text into a field. Same result as above.

As with the original post, this seems to afflict only the TC field code. Other codes work fine, including TOC. And if I create a TOC field, then edit the code to TC, it immediately loses its properties as a field. If I then put the O back in, it immediately behaves as a field once again. Unlike in the original post, adjusting the settings for field display and/or hidden text, have no impact.

In the end, the only solution was to create the field using Alt + Shift + o to open the Mark Table of Contents Entry dialog box. And finally, this works!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30899794)